# Managing images in Media Manager on Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, lightbox

I am new in Joomla environment and I have a question regarding Media Manager. I uploaded some images on the Media Manager and I successfully put it on my LightBox Plugin. However, I need to set the Order of each images on Media Manager. Is that even possible? or do I need to use other modules for that? please help me.

Right now I can only upload them, but I can't order how they appear in the gallery.  How can we accomplish this?

Comment: Which of the hundreds of light-box plug-ins is it?

Comment: You could rename them and re-upload in the right sequence if it's only a few. If others need to manage them however by all means do get a dedicated extension,you could start checking http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images

Comment: Currently, I used this one: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/content-photo-gallery/1468   . This is a free version(Simple Image Gallery). But this version has no feature to Organize photos in the gallery. I am thinking to use Simple Image Gallery Pro(http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/commercial-premium/simple-image-gallery-pro). Does Simple Image Gallery Pro has feature to Organize/Order photos in the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

You can't order the images using the Media Manager as it simply allows you to upload images. There might be an option with the lightbox extension you're using to order the images. If not, try using another extension such as the Yootheme [Wigetkit](http://www.yootheme.com/widgetkit/downloads). It's a component that comes with a Lightbox and allows you to upload and order the images